# Web Application Scanner

Tags: security, scripting, web-applications, database-security

I want to develop a web applications to collect or exchange sensitive or personal data.

This system would give user a detailed automated report on:

- How secure user's website is?
- How easily it can be hacked?
- Where exactly is the problem and
- What are the remedies?

Comment: I suggest narrowing down your feature list. What do you mean by "how secure"? Are you looking for XSS? SQL injections? Malicious code? Admin password "123"?

Answer (score 1):

HP Webinspect should help you in securing your web applications:

http://webappsecure.blogspot.in/2012/07/hp-webinspect-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

HP has a tool called [WebInspect](https://download.hpsmartupdate.com/webinspect/) that does something similar to this. You may want to look at their tool.